# Is there any way to retrieve what a customer purchased (e.g. product id, product description,etc.) from the Stripe-Zapier integration?

Tags: stripe-payments, zapier

Is there any way to retrieve what a customer purchased (e.g. product id, product description,etc.) from the Stripe-Zapier integration?  Nothing pertinent to the sale is being passed except for price which when there is more than one product with the same price there is no way to automate on the back end.  Thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide more detail here to allow anyone to help you. How are you creating payments? What is this integration via Zapier? How are you receiving the data? Where would you want to inspect these details? You might be able to use `metadata` to accomplish this, or retrieve Checkout `line_items` if you use Checkout.

Comment: It depends how you capturing a payment. If the payment is against an order then it always contains an all these info..